# What is relation between weight and height in hydraulic lift?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

I am trying to lift a 10kg weight using 1kg weight as shown in diagram.

[image]

block A is 1kg and block B is 10kg will the lighter block be able to lift the heavier block. Also what will bw the height by which the heavier block will be lift.

is it possible and if yes what will be the height by which weight can be lifted.

Comment: Hey Tank, since your question is not conceptual but rather a "do my homework" question, i would recommend you to edit your question and show what you have tried to solve the problem, and where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the block A of weight $W_A$ be lowered by height $H_A$ to lift block $B$ of weight $W_B$ by height $H_B$.

Using Law of Conservation of Energy (Assuming ideal conditions),

Decrease in $P.E.$ of  block A, $W_Ah_A$ ($\mathrm{weight\times height})$ is equal to increase in $P.E.$ of block B, $W_Bh_B$
$$W_Ah_A=W_Bh_B$$